# why im getting error npm ERR! core-js@3.6.4 postinstall

Tags: node.js, npm, github-actions

Im running GitHub workflow with job

```
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci --loglevel error
```

when I execute workflow I get next error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! path sh
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! core-js@3.6.4 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! spawn sh ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@3.6.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-06-20T11_16_26_282Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Delete the node_modules directory and the package-lock.json file from your project. and run  npm install again maybe will help